# Two column data with multiple minimums

Tags: python

I am trying to read two column data and find all the minimums it has. Graph looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Majv.png)

x axis is time and y axis is flux. Data can be seen with this link
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1E870F010DBA8407!298&authkey=!ABdG6FJ_i3d9oWI&ithint=file%2ctxt
I couldn't find a cool algorithm. I also tried to fit a curve to define minimums easily but the result weren't correct. Which statical method is suitable for this job. I used python and C. 
I ll be happy if you share your ideas.

Comment: Isn't a minimum just defined as all i for which y[i-1]>y[i]<y[i+1]?

Comment: you are right i used many variation of it but data is not regular ascending. The line appears straight but it also has many minimums. I am trying to find real local minimums others are not important. even and odd minimums are releated with each other. There is a fixed time between them but other curves differ from this one. so i can't use the relation between them.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to sort the list of points along the x axis, otherwise it is going to be an absolute pain. Then you can use:

```
minima_indices=[i+1 for i,y in enumerate(y_list[1:-1]) if y_list[i-1]>=y<=y_list[i+1]]
```

This should give you the indices of the minima in the sorted list. Note that it omits the first and last point, if you want them to be included this can be done easily.

If you only want the deep minima in your graph then you can filter out all the small minima at the end (or during the original list comprehension by adding a condition):

```
def approx(a,b,tol):
    if abs(a-b)<tol: return True
    return False

minima_indices_filtered=[i for i in minima_indices if not approx(y_list[i],y_0,tol)]
```

y_0 is the value of the flat line at the top of your picture, and tol is how deep a minima has to be before it registers as being a minima.

Comment: you had nearly written whole program but i again failed. I think first ı must scan my python notes to define my mistakes. Again thank you for your answer.

Comment: There was a typo in my first line of code which I only just caught: <= instead of >= which will cause it to not work. Have a look at whether that was the problem.